# Adding a custom option to a view bag list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is the code I have to get a list of certifications. I want to also add the word "All" to the list. How would I do that? When I try `+ "ALL"` at the end of the statement it does not work.

```
ViewBag.CertificationList = (from r in _context.INT_Certifications select r.Certification).Distinct();
```

Comment: What does it mean `it does not work`?

Comment: did we help your gouvernment? ;)

Comment: Yes ;) we are thankfull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried something like this? (untested):

```
var lst = (from r in _context.INT_Certifications select r.Certification).Distinct().ToList();
lst.add("all");
ViewBag.CertificationList = lst;
```

Comment: (`Distinct().ToList()` *\*cough\** ;) )

Comment: Actually. How would I add it as the first item in the list.

Comment: Use lst.Insert(0, "all");

Answer (score 2):

> I want to also add the word "All" to the list

I am going to take you by the word here :) Try this:

```
List<string> res = (from r in _context.INT_Certifications select r.Certification).Distinct().ToList();
res.Add(" All");
ViewBag.CertificationList = res;
```

> When I try + "ALL" at the end of the statement it does not work.

Because you are trying to concatenate a `string` to a `IEnumerable<string>`

`IEnumerable<string>` does not know the `+` operator. If you want to have the elements of an enumeration in a string you can tranform it like this:

```
string allItems = String.Join(" ", ViewBag.CertificationList) + " All";
```

Comment: OP’s `CertificationList` is an `IEnumerable`, so it does not have an `Add`.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: [`List<T>.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1.aspx) is unfortunately not fluent but returns void, so you need to assign the list to the viewbag separately from your `Add` call.

Comment: @poke ach, those adhoc changes.... thank you again. I should paste the code more often simply into LinqPad before posting it ;)

Comment: Yeah, you should… sorry but one more xD – `res.ToList().Add()` will throw away the list, and then you assign the (unchanged) enumerable to the view bag.

Comment: @poke :D that was indeed a long day :D thank you for the effort to improve my answer. and teaching me thoroughness ;)

Comment: @poke hallarious, I bow before you :) next drink's on me ;) (thanx for the edit)

Comment: :D :D :D This time I thought I should just fix it myself to avoid any more confusion.. what a day! xD (and you’re welcome :D)